# Get callback when wifi connected, no Internet state Android?

Tags: android, networking, intentfilter

I am using below Intent Filters to recieve network connectivity callbacks

```
IntentFilter filter=new IntentFilter();
filter.addAction("android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE");
filter.addAction("android.net.wifi.WIFI_STATE_CHANGED");
filter.addAction(WifiManager.SUPPLICANT_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION);
```

But in below observations, It fails at 4th Scenario(highlighted).

**Scenarios I have tried and observed:**

1) My mobile has both Wifi and Mobile Data turned ON (Both have active Internet connection) --> Getting network callback

2) My mobile has turned off Wifi and turned on Mobile Data (None of them have active internet connection) --> Getting network Callback

3) Turning off one of the Mobile's Mobile Data or wifi --> Getting Callback

> 4) My mobile has both Wifi and Mobile Data turned On ( Wifi doesn't
>   have active internet connection and mobile data has) --> Not getting
>   callback

**Can any one please suggest me how to get callback when Wifi has not active internet connection irrespective of Mobile Data is Off or ON ?**